NextJs Jest module import alias not resolving properly
In my very basic unit test, Jest not resolving the import alias properly.
app\page.tsx
import { getRandomLocation } from "@/lib/services/util-service";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import add from "@/cmsService";

export default async function Home() {
  const app = getRandomLocation();
  console.log(app);
  const sum = add(1,2);
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.description}>
        <h1>
          NextJs 14.2 Demo
        </h1>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

tests\page.tsx
import Home from '@/app/page';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('app/page', () => {
  it('renders app page', async () => {
    render(await Home());
    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: /NextJs 14.2 Demo/i,
    });
    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

lib\services\cms-service.ts
export const getRandomNumber = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) - 1;

export const add = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;

export default add;

Error:
PS C:\NextJS\next-14-2-demo> npm run test

redroof.com@0.1.0 test
jest --no-cache

FAIL  tests/page.test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module '../cmsService' from 'app/page.tsx'

Require stack:
  app/page.tsx
  __tests__/page.test.tsx

  12 |         <h1>
  13 |           NextJs 14.2 Demo
> 14 |         </h1>
     |                                                      ^
  15 |       </div>
  16 |     </main>
  17 |   );

  at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/page.tsx:14:60)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/page.test.tsx:5:54)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.46 s
ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@/cmsService": ["./lib/services/cms-service"]
    },
    "types": ["jest", "node", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

jest.config.js
`const nextJest = require('next/jest');
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig'); // replace with the path to your tsconfig.json file

const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: './' });

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  rootDir: './',
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths , { prefix: '<rootDir>/' } )
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);`

Tried all possible Regex possibilities in moduleNameMapper like
"@/cmsService" : "/lib/service/cms-service",
"^@/cmsService$" : "/lib/service/cms-service" etc. but all fails.
